# Placing the sorting icon right to head text for a dynamic div?

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic parent div has width in percentage inside that  I have a div with sorting icon and text ,I just want sorting icon place right of heading text.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GONp2.jpg) is the attached output I want to achieve.

```css
.parent{ width:150px; border:1px solid red} 
.fa-caret-up:after{ content: "v"; border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span>display inline not working</span>
<span class="fa-caret-up"></span>
</div>
```

i want caret icon right top after text

Comment: try .parent{display : flex;} for parent div

Comment: display:flex not work because its create block according to word or icon width

Comment: i had attached a image like i want\

Comment: But display:flex is doing the same thing.

Comment: yes i just want right after the finishes text

Comment: Can i use extra p tag inside span tag? @AshokYadav

Answer (score 0):

check this hope this solve your problem 
Top right

```css
.parent{ width:150px; border:1px solid red} 
.fa-caret-up:after{ content: "v"; border:1px solid red;float:right}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span class="fa-caret-up"></span>
<span>display inline not working</span>
</div>
```

On the right after the text

```css
.parent{ width:150px; border:1px solid red} 
.fa-caret-up:after{ content: "v"; border:1px solid red;float:right}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span>display inline not working</span>
<span class="fa-caret-up"></span>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: not want right of parent div  just right at text has finishes.
after 'not'

Comment: are you able to make changes in your html?

Comment: sir is that any way the v icon place after 'not' or span block

Comment: it is after the span with the text problem is you width

Answer (score 0):

You could eventually try to use `display: flex`

**Edit**

You can apply `flex: 0 0 auto; max-width: 100%;` to `.fa-caret-up` only, it's closer to the result you want.

```css
.parent{ width:150px; border:1px solid red; display: flex; } 
.fa-caret-up { flex: 0 0 auto; max-width: 100%;}
.fa-caret-up:after{ content: "v"; border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span>display inline not working</span>
<span class="fa-caret-up"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Bro, i just want v icon after text block at the right after 'not'

Comment: You said your width is dynamic, there are many more or less ugly ways to put something in the middle of a text, but nothing bulletproof.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fixed table-layout on the parent element and just set the width of the first child span. You can use `margin` on the pseudo `:after` element to indent the space between the icon and the text.

Here is an example

```css
.parent { 
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  white-space: wrap;
}

.fa-caret-up:after { 
  content: "v"; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.parent span {
  display: table-cell;
}

.parent span:first-child {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span>display inline not working</span>
  <span class="fa-caret-up"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks sir, table-layout: fixed; work nice, but i can give span fixed width because i have single line text also come in <thead> of table heading

Answer (score 0):

```
    .parent {
     border: 1px solid #f00;
    }
    
    .caret {
     display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px; /* if required */
    }
    
    .caret:after {
     content: '\2191';
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
   <div class="parent">
 <span class="caret">Some text</span>
</div>
```